# Add typed additional attributes to an existing document elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, document, updating

I added a field to the document:

```
POST /erection/shop/1/_update
{
  "doc": {
    "my_field":""
  }
}
```

The new field is assigned to the type of "String". how can I create a new field with the type "Boolean"/"Integer"?

and 2nd question:
is it possible to add one field in all documents using one query? (without updating each document)

Comment: Are you sure about your index name ? j/k ;-)

Comment: What's wrong with my index name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Explicitly define a mapping **prior** to the first update you do.

2) No, you can't. You can do it in your application using "scan" and then "bulk update"

Comment: Thank you for your answers
1) All works, thx
2) Could you give an example of how to do a *scan* and *bulk update*. Which query can I use for that?